# Ajax text field to divtag1 and other text field to divtag2 using php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Ajax - POST</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    var data = 'name='+$('#nm').val();
    var data = 'name='+$('#sn').val();
    $.post('script.php', data, function(response){
      $('#dv').html(response);
      $('#dv2').html(response);
    });

    return false;      // required to not open the page when form is submited
  });
});
--></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dv">Here will be displayed the response.</div><br />
<form action="script.php" method="post">
 Name: <input type="text" name="nm" id="nm" /><br />
<div id="dv2">Here will be displayed the 2nd response.</div><br />
 Second name: <input type="text" name="sn" id="sn" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want Name to post to JavaScript and come out under divtag (dv) and second name to come out  into (dv2) - I looked around all I ever seem to find is just how to echo variable out in one div tag.

Comment: You have `var data = ...` twice...

Comment: Do you want to display the values of nm and sn in dv and dv2 ?

Comment: I want to display 2 different Values in both Divs so what ever goes in text box one would display its on result in dv and what ever goes in text box 2 would display its own result not the both results in both divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. You declared the same name for the data passed to script.php . here is the edited code.It is working.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Ajax - POST</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    var nm = $('#nm').val(); // changes made
    var sn= $('#sn').val();
    $.post('script.php',{
    name1:nm,
    name2:sn
  }, function(response){
      var resp=response.split("."); // spiltting into different output
      $('#dv').html(resp[0]);
      $('#dv2').html(resp[1]);
    });

    return false;      // required to not open the page when form is submited
  });
});
--></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dv">Here will be displayed the response.</div><br />
<form method="post"> // no need to specify script.php here
 Name: <input type="text" name="nm" id="nm" /><br />
<div id="dv2">Here will be displayed the 2nd response.</div><br />
 Second name: <input type="text" name="sn" id="sn" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

get the parameter in script.php as follows

```
<?php 

String name1 =$_POST["name1"];
String name2= $_POST["name2"];
// do your calculations

String together= name1 +"."+ name2; // just make different output together as one string
out.print(together);
?>
```

Comment: script.php has my formulas : say i was to put in a number it would work out the code and i want it to appear next to the text box. Also when i put a number in the other text box so when i press submit i have 2 different formula out comes next to each text box ( NOTE: Not Repeating What ever is Echo'ed out in to both Div's. Thanks in advanced

Comment: I didnt get you. Did you check the above code working or not. i just gave a sample on how to get value in script.php. You can use your own coding in php file

Comment: Yes I checked the Above. This Works i have had it all working in 1Div with all the results. but what i want is if i Type example: 10 in (nm) and my script.php collects (nm) and then my formula wants to do (nm)*10 and i get an answer i want it sitting next to the text box but in the same instances what ever is put in (sn) example: 12 in sn it would (sn)*10 and put answer next to the text field on submit.

Comment: I had it updated . You can use json too in order to pass array. This is the simplest method. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this i Will check it when i get a chance Tomorrow i off work all day. i will message tomorrow see how it get on